# Migration to Compose MongoDB on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, add-on

We use old add-on Mongodb classic which will reach [end of life](https://www.compose.com/articles/retiring-mongodb-classic-on-compose/) soon. We must migrate to the new one Compose Mongodb but I've noticed that [Compose](https://www.compose.com) discontinued it and it will be soon migrated to [IBM cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/databases-for-mongodb). It is even not possible to create MongoDB on Compose since Feb 2019.

Ok, but there is another Mongodb add-on: [mLab MongoDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab). Unfortunatelly there is another cach: [mLab is acquired by MongoDB, Inc](https://blog.mlab.com/2018/10/mlab-is-becoming-a-part-of-mongodb-inc/) and mLab is being migrated to [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).

So where should be migrate to avoid another migration withing a year? Is it worth to migrate to Compose MongoDB and then wait until we must migrate it to IBM Cloud or should we directly migrate to Atlas?

Answer (score 0):

For IBM Cloud, you will want to look at [Databases for MongoDB](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/databases-for-mongodb.)

You can review the differences between Compose on IBM Cloud and Databases for MongoDB [here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/ibm-cloud-databases-the-next-generation-of-ibm-compose.).

Ultimately, Atlas and Databases for MongoDB both have different platform feature sets, pricing, and integrations. Ultimately, the choice is based on your requirements and preferences.

One neat thing about Databases for MongoDB is that it allows you to control disk and RAM completely independently, unlike the instance sizes found on Compose Heroku add-on or Atlas (at least based on their public pricing)

Hope this helps!

If you reach out to Compose support, we can help out.

Answer (score 0):

Another Heroku add-on option to consider is [ObjectRocket](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/ormongo).

You can find details on the [ObjectRocket MongoDB offering](https://www.objectrocket.com/mongodb-heroku) to see if it fits your use case.

If you decide you do want to migrate to ObjectRocket, these [self-service docs](https://docs.objectrocket.com/mongodb_compose_migration.html) will help you gauge the level of effort required.

Stay on the lookout for a MongoDB migration tool in coming weeks that will automate most of the migration steps to switch over from the Compose add-on to ObjectRocket.

Good luck!

Disclosure: I work for ObjectRocket.